# paths in a weighted directed trees

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

Given an weighted directed tree, I have to write this:

Given a vertex `v`, I should list all the vertex `c` such that there exist a path
whose origin is in `c` and whose end is in `v`

Given a vertex `v`, I should list all the vertex `c` such that there exist a path
whose origin is in `v` and whose end is in `c`

What is the easiest way to do this in Mathematica?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What relevance do the weights have to the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[vcIn, vcOut]
vcIn = Rest @ VertexInComponent @ ## &;
vcOut = Rest @ VertexOutComponent @ ## &;
```

Examples:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
vcIn[g, 3]
```

> {2, 1}

```
vcOut[g, 2]
```

> {3, 4}

Answer (score 2):

Like with all `Graphs`, you can use `FindPath`.

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
c = 1;
v = 3;
FindPath[g, c, v, ∞, 1]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}}